# varios files like `MbcYHt` all over my filesystem. where are they coming from?

Tags: filesystems, administration, temporary-files

Recently, I noted that some directories of my server are cluttered with files like `MbcYHt`, `KZDmv_`, `K40bS9`, etc., i.e. always a filename of size 6 which seems to be base64 encoded. The file size is always zero.

Some more properties:

```
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 24 20:00 X2OMrP
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 20 13:00 XN2vPY
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 24 08:00 Xu12IS
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 24 11:00 XVHHvw
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 14 13:00 Y2LyF0
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 25 03:00 Yf8Cwq
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 24 18:00 YJewCl
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 25 08:00 YkEeUU
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 14 10:00 ZPuqhb
-rw-------  1 root root      0 Jan 20 09:00 Zz0VWp
```

There are really *many* such files.

I wonder where they are coming from. I.e. if someone maybe recognize this and had some similar problems. Maybe that is some filesystem (ReiserFS) related problem. Or Gentoo/Portage specific (I run something like `emerge --update --deep world` automatically via cron every week.). Or maybe related to `rsync` (the whole filesystem is copied via `rsync` to some backup location every day). Or maybe related to Git (many directories are under Git version control).

Some directories where I found such files:

- /
- /scripts (custom directory with some user scripts, mostly Python)
- /tmp
- /var/tmp

(And I think some others, I partly deleted them already, I don't remember exactly anymore.)

Of course, maybe the most obvious reason is that some of the scripts in `/scripts` is messed up somehow and created them.